# how to take a input of very big length in java

Tags: java, input, io

I want to take an integer as input whose maximum value is 10^100000.

How to take such input in java

I took

```
long num;
```

but it didnot work

any suggestion?

Comment: Use [BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: BigInteger, or use apfloat.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the BigInteger class, which is an arbitrary-precision integer class.

You can create one with a `String` argument, like so:

```
String longIntegerString = "10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000";
BigInteger bigInteger = new BigInteger(longIntegerString);
```

The class contains add(), subtract(),  multiply(), divide(), mod() and other mathematical functions.

See the javadocs here:

[BigInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: I believe it is -(2^(2^32)) - 2^(2^32 -1) - 1.

Comment: in the example u have given lets say iwant to take a substring.
but substring method only takes (int ) as parameter how to get through it?

Comment: Let me correct myself, first: The range is: -(2^(2^31)) to 2^(2^31 -1) - 1

Comment: Second, let me clarify: You want to pass a BigInteger to the String.substring(int a, int b) method?

Comment: no actually my objective is to find a substring from that biginteger and take modulus

Comment: `String s = bigInteger.toString(); String subString = s.substring(a,b); bigInteger = new BigInteger(subString); bigInteger = bigInteger.mod(bigInteger2);`, where a and b are int variables and bigInteger2 is the BigInteger representing the modulus. That should do it.

Comment: I have taken both p & q as BigInteger.
but it showing error
 `   error: inconvertible types
                  if((q.mod(p))==0)
                                                  ^
  required: BigInteger
  found:    int
1 error`

Comment: You want to check against: `if(q.mod(p).equals(BigInteger.ZERO))`.

Comment: We have already gone far beyond the original scope of this question. Refer to the documentation or post a new question if you have any more questions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use BigInteger to store large input.

You can take input as text and then parse it using BigInteger.